# Padding bottom won't work

Tags: html, css

How do I make img to be floated on right side with bottom padding of 50px?

When I insert my code there is only white space of 50px at a bottom of image.

```css
section img{
    float: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <img src="if_60-rss_104443.png">
</section>
```

Comment: Your `img` isn't wrapped in a `section` tag, so the CSS selector doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to include `section` element. In your CSS you applying styles to `img` inside `section` element, just add it to your html:

```css
section img {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom:  50px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="if_60-rss_104443.png">
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to align the image in the section, you can use the text-align.

```css
section {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <img src="if_60-rss_104443.png">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS rule only applies when the image is inside a `section` element. Then it works as expected (I added a red border to demonstrate it):

```css
section img {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/555">
</section>
```